# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm new to python, using the latest version. I have found a nice script that runs searches on Presearch.com. However i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable pointing at:
line 13, in <module>
    token = soup.find("input", {
```

How do i fix this? Here's the code

```py
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

email = "Enter your email"
password = "Enter your password"

r = requests.Session()
content = r.get("https://www.presearch.org").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find("input", {
    "name": "_token"
})["value"]

payload = "_token={}&login_form=1&email={}&password={}".format(token, email, password)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

login = r.post("https://www.presearch.org/api/auth/login", data=payload, headers=headers)

for x in range(0, 10):
    words = random.choice(
        ["apple", "life", "hacker", "facebook", "abeyancies", "abeyancy", "abeyant", "abfarad", "abfarads", "abhenries",
         "abhenry", "abhenrys", "abhominable", "abhor", "abhorred", "abhorrence", "abhorrences", "abhorrencies",
         "abhorrency", "abhorrent", "abhorrently", "abhorrer", "abhorrers", "abhorring", "abhorrings", "abhors", "abid",
         "abidance", "abidances", "abidden", "abide", "abided", "abider", "abiders", "abides", "abiding", "abidingly",
         "abidings", "abies", "abietic", "abigail", "abigails", "abilities", "ability", "abiogeneses", "abiogenesis",
         "abiogenetic", "abiogenetically", "abiogenic", "abiogenically", "abiogenist", "abiogenists", "abiological",
         "abioses", "abiosis", "abiotic", "abiotically", "abiotrophic", "abiotrophies", "abiotrophy"])
payload = "term={}&provider_id=98&_token={}".format(words, token)
r.post("https://www.presearch.org/search", data=payload, headers=headers)
print("Term:{} Search done!".format(words))
time.sleep(10)
r = r.get("https://www.presearch.org/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
balance = soup.find("span", {
    "class": "number ajax balance"
})
print("Your Balance: {} PRE".format(balance.text))
```

Comment: That means it's not finding the `input` element that you're looking for. You need to check for ths before trying to access `["value"]`.

Comment: There's no `<input name="_token">` on that page. The input input is `name="q"`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, `find()` could not find the input you want and returned `None`, but the code `["value"]` is trying to get a key named value from `None`, by iterating over it, assuming that `find()` will always return a dictionary. The `subscriptable` means something that can be iterated and `None` cannot be iterated, so this hopefully makes the error clearer.

One way to avoid this error when a element could not be found would be:

```
token = soup.find("input", {
    "name": "_token"
})

if not token:
  # Do something if find() could not find the element
```